# Show active plugins in Sublime Text and disable them

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I just installed sublime text 2 and was overwhelmed by the php plugins that I installed ALL of them. Now auto-complete is crazy, a million unnecessary suggestions and I dont remember which plugin does what or which ones I installed. Is there a way to see all active plugins for a particular file so I can disable some?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P - and there are `Package Control: Enable Package` and `Package Control: Disable Package`

Comment: FYI everyone: most, if not all, of the answers here also apply to Sublime Text 3 and 4.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not sure about the active plugin on a file part, but you can quickly go in and remove plugins that are installed by opening the Command Pallete (Cmd-Shift-P on Mac) and typing remove if you have Package Control installed.

You will see **Package Control: Remove Package****

**Once the list of installed plugins shows up you can click these and remove them and then test out your code.**

You can do the reverse and quickly re-install the packages if something you needed was missing.

You probably already knew this so I am not sure that this will be helpful or not.

*BTW: Sublime Text 3 Beta just came out and is available to licensed users.  I have not done much with it yet, but it loads almost instantly.*

Comment: Sublime Text 3 has same behaviour !

Answer (score 8):

There's **no need to remove packages** as packages can be simply *disabled* by using `Package Control: Disable Package` option in the *Command Palette*.

Comment: This also works in Sublime Text 3 and 4.

Answer (score 6):

Click on `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User` to see a list of the installed packages. It will looks something like this:

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Package Control",
        "PyCover",
        "Python 3",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-csslint",
        "SublimeLinter-html-tidy",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint",
        "SublimeLinter-json",
        "SublimeLinter-lua",
        "SublimeLinter-pyflakes",
        "SublimeLinter-pyyaml",
        "SublimeREPL"
    ]
}
```

You can't disable packages, but you can remove them. Click on `Preferences > Package Control` and enter `Package Control: Remove Package`, then select the package.

Comment: seems you can disable packae from package: disable